# show text inside div on hover not working in css

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("assets/images/bg.jpg")no-repeat top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.category-container {
  width: 87%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

.category-container h2 {
  margin: 2% auto;
  background-color: #fc0321;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 15%;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 47em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.thumb div {
  position: relative;
}

.thumb div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.thumb div img {
  width: 36.8em;
  height: 22em;
}

.thumb div h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity ease-out 250ms;
}

.thumb div:hover .thumb div h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="category-container">
  <h2>Category</h2>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div><img src="assets/images/header1.jpg" />
      <h3>Click to open</h3>
    </div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/header2.jpg" />
      <h3>Click to open</h3>
    </div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/header3.jpg" />
      <h3>Click to open</h3>
    </div>
    <div><img src="assets/images/header4.jpeg" />
      <h3>Click to open</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to apply css hover to my div element which is inside the div having class of thumb. I want to make opacity of text to be 1 on hover. But it is not working. Why it is not working? Please help me on this problem. Can anyone help me regarding this problem? Is there any mistake in my code? If I made any mistake please help with that.

Comment: Maybe `.thumb div:hover h3{ opacity: 1;}`

Comment: As @codesayan replied you dont need to tell again al the path of your h3 once you hover his relative parent.

Comment: Typo?  You have pasted `.thumb div` twice

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to

```
    .thumb div h3:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Because you want to hover the images and the text appear so the hover should be behind the "h3". and it's become `.thumb div h3:hover`